# Python - Removing space in a string

Tags: python

So, I would like to print a string with an exclamation mark at the end of the statement but without any space between the last word and the exclamation mark.
For instance:

```
name = raw_input('Insert your name: ')
```

Now, I would like python to print something like this:

> Your name is John!

So, I type:

```
print 'Your name is', name, '!'
```

And it returns me:

> Your name is John !

What I want to do is to remove the space between the "John" and the exclamation mark.

Any ideas?

Comment: `print "Your name is %s!" % (name)`

Comment: from subject, before I read the text, I was going to answer, " ".join(s.split())

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
print 'Your name is {}!'.format(name)
```

or:

```
print 'your name is %s!' %name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of `,`

```
print 'Your name is' + name + '!'
```

However, why will you remove the space between them, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I came along this old topic and thought I might know a newer way to do this:

`print(f'Your name is {name}!')`

[This source](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) tells it is part of the game since v3.6.